Oracle composite index with range conditions
I'm switching from mysql DB to use oracle 19c
I need to create/adapt my indexes to support range conditions:
I have a queries like this:
select * from mytable where mydate>? and mytype=?

I have an index on mytavble(mydate,mytype)
According to MySQL,once you reach the first range condition, any subsequent condition in your query will not use any further columns.
Why can't mysql use also the second indexed column mytype?
And is this also true with oracle?

Oracle will open an INDEX RANGE SCAN but will scan all entries with mydate higher than the bind variable and ignore (filter) the entries with different mytype than required.
This will be very ineffective if you have for each mydate a large number of mytype.
Here you see it in the execution plan
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into    plan_table  FOR
select * from mytable where mydate>:1 and mytype=:2;

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |         |   500 |   982K|    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MYTABLE |   500 |   982K|    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX     |    90 |       |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("MYDATE">:1 AND "MYTYPE"=TO_NUMBER(:2) AND "MYDATE" IS NOT NULL)
       filter("MYTYPE"=TO_NUMBER(:2))

Obviously better index for the query is the one with the opposite order of the columns - first the column with the equal predicate
create index idx2 on mytable (mytype,mydate);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |         |   500 |   982K|    93   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MYTABLE |   500 |   982K|    93   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX2    |    90 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("MYTYPE"=TO_NUMBER(:2) AND "MYDATE">:1 AND "MYDATE" IS NOT NULL)

You see there is no filter only the appropriate rows are selected. Also the estimated cost are lower 3compared to 30.
I can't speak for MySQL, but suspect this will be the same behavior.

Correct. Just may want to adjust the language: in the first paragraph there is no "skipping" while applying the equality predicate - every row in the index leaf blocks after the initial seek on the start date is checked individually.

Thanks for comment @PaulW I edited the answer using ignore instead of skip to avoid the confusion with skip scan

Oracle will use its binary tree search (seek) algorithm on each column starting on the left until it reaches a column that you do not have an equality predicate (=) on, whether because you aren't filtering on it at all, or because you are using a non-equality predicate (<, >, between, !=, etc.). From that point on for all remaining columns to the right, the binary tree is no longer used, but Oracle scans through all the rows in the leaf nodes following a linked list between nodes.
Unless it opts for a "skip scan" in which case, once it hits a column without an equality predicate but sees you have  important predicates on further columns to the right, it will repeat a binary search/seek operation for every distinct value of the "skipped" column. If the skipped column has only a few distinct values, this is pretty efficient. If it has many values (like a date), it is very inefficient.
So as a rule of thumb when using multi-column ("concatenated") indexes, place the columns most likely to have equality predicates applied on the left, and those less likely on the right.
